# How to scroll to an element WITHIN a div, without scrolling entire page (no JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a scrollable div with a bunch of h3 elements. I want to click a button to scroll a specific h3 element within that div. NOT scrolling the entire page. Is this behavior possible **without using JQuery?** My app is built in React, so npm library suggestions are welcome too! Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind setting an `id` to the specific `h3`:

```html
<div>
  <!-- The content of the div -->

  <h3 id="foo">
    Foo
  </h3>

  <h3 id="bar">
    Bar
  </h3>

  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

you can then tell the browser to navigate to the `h3` element using a link pointing to the `id` using the hash:

```html
<a href="#foo">
  <button>
    Go to Foo
  </button>
</a>
```

else, you can use the Javascript `.scrollIntoView()` function while targeting the correct `h3` element:

```js
// Consider the h3 element is referenced by the 'h3' variable

h3.scrollIntoView();
```

as stated on [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

See example:

```js
// Wait for window to load before adding listeners
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // The button that needs to trigger the scrolling event
  const button = document.querySelector('button.clickable');
  
  // The h3 element to scroll to
  const h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
  
  // Add the click listener
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    h3.scrollIntoView();
  });
});
```

```css
h3 {
  /* Make the h3 elements really distanced from other elements to test the scrolling  */
  margin: 500px auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#foo">
    <button>
      Goto <code>foo</code> using <code>id</code>
    </button>
  </a>
  
  <button class="clickable">
    Goto <code>foo</code> using <code>scrollIntoView</code>
  </button>
  
  <h3 id="foo">
    Foo
  </h3>
</div>
```

EDIT 1: switched `button` and `a` HTML components to make the `a` the parent container of the `button`

EDIT 2: added code snippet

Answer (score 1):

```js
var hello = document.getElementById("hello");
var bye = document.getElementById("bye");
function goHello(){
  hello.scrollIntoView({block: "start"});
}
function goBye(){
  bye.scrollIntoView({block: "start"});
}
```

```css
#divScroll{
  max-height:180px;
  overflow:auto;
  background : #FFCC00;
  padding:20px
}
```

```html
<div id="divScroll">
<h3 id="hello">Hello</h3>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h3 id="bye">Bye</h3>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<button onClick="goHello()">Go Hello</button> 
<button onClick="goBye()">Go Bye</button>
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Style each h3 with height and overflow-y: scroll;

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking about, they are asking how to scroll *to* an h3 that is among many sibling h3's, not how to scroll inside of an h3